# How does this jQuery code work(i.e what would be put into the variables)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reporting-services

I'm studying this jQuery code that takes the web-page generated by SSRS Report Viewer, and then overlays it with a datepicker( standard jQuery ).

here , we look for the input text box that takes in a date:

```
var span = innerTable.find("span:contains('Date')");
if (span) {
    var innerRow = $(span).parent().parent();
    var innerCell =  innerRow.find("td").eq(1);
    var textFrom = innerCell.find("input[type=text]");
    innerCell = innerRow.find("td").eq(4);
    var textTo = innerCell.find("input[type=text]"); 
}
```

so I'm curious about what kind of value goes into the variable `textTo` . That's because later in the code, we say:

```
$(textTo).focus(function () {
    $(textTo).datepicker("show");   
});
```

Also, what does `focus(function ()` do ?

any tips appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems like it would be a *date*

Comment: @ExplosionPills   - hmm, let me study this. OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be the [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) representing the `input[type=text]` nodes. (Note: in your scenario, there is probably only one such node, but you should know that [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) returns *all* nodes that match the selector.) It's basically jQuery's wrapping of all of the information representing *that specific DOM object*. You can use the object to get various information about the `input` element—like its `value`, CSS styling, parents, etc—and also use it to manipulate the element—remove it, add something before it, or perhaps add an event listener.

Here's a code walkthrough:

```
var innerRow = $(span).parent().parent(); // the grandparent of the `span` node
var innerCell =  innerRow.find("td").eq(1); // the second (index 1) table cell inside the row we just found in the previous line
var textFrom = innerCell.find("input[type=text]"); // the input elements inside that cell
innerCell = innerRow.find("td").eq(4); // the fifth (index 4) table cell inside the row from line 1
var textTo = innerCell.find("input[type=text]"); // the input elements inside the cell found in the previous line
```

As to the second part of your question, the [`focus` listener](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) will execute a function when the `input` element has gained focus—i.e., the cursor moves inside it. That can happen when the user clicks directly inside the element or tabs to it from another element in the form. Specifically your code says: when this `input` gains focus, show the datepicker.